# How to saturate network connections/sec with threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking

I have created a simple Azure web service (that just echos back string passed to it) and I wanted to saturate the service with as much network connections as possible using a desktop .Net app. The desktop app is something like this:

```
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
        while (running)
        {
            if (m_working.Count < max_threads && m_queue.Count > 0)
            {
                Queue q = m_queue[0];
                q.timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                q.thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadWorker));

                m_working.Add(q);
                m_queue.Remove(q);

                q.thread.Start(q);
                while (!q.thread.IsAlive) ;
            }
            ...
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
```

Inside ThreadWorker() is the code that contains WebClient object using the DownloadString() function.

For the web app, I have set:

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="500"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
<system.web>
```

When I run the app, I only manage to get maximum of about ~65 connections/s. Setting the Thread sleep time to lower value does not improve the performance. However if I run another instance of the app, the 2nd app would still show ~65 connections/s and the 1st instance is not affected.

Did I did something wrong with my code? How can I write the code so that the connections could be saturated, maybe perhaps 1000 or 10,000 connections/s?

Or is this some kind of fundamental limit on the C#/.Net library thing? Please help thanks.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/18667011-c034-43bc-ab2e-0e87bf811e5e/windows-7-increase-the-limit-of-concurrent-tcp-connections-not-related-to-eula-file-sharing?forum=w7itpronetworking

Comment: How do you measure 65 connections/sec??? Are you opening and closing connections? Sleeping 5 seconds you would just decrease throughput. I would expect you measure concurrent connections.

Comment: Hi, every connections has a Queue class associated with it, once a file is downloaded the state will be changed and the thread knows it. From there a event is fired/called; a simple counter is used to record the no# of file download completed for every second. Btw the Sleep time is in milliseconds..